# suricata url_decode and base64_decode

Tags: suricata

In Suricata 6.0.0 beta 1, I noticed that the url_decode rule keyword is added.
And why url_decode supported in transformation while base64_decode implemented in another way? For example, it needs base64_decode combining with base64_data to alert?
It seems more **reasonable** to design the base64_decode in transformation just like url_decode.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess base64_decode can support all kinds of buffers instead url_decode is not applied to all buffers yet.